# GraphicsMagick watermark

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to get an image to have a big ugly transparent ALPHA in it. So far, I have this code:

```
gm convert \
    -background transparent \
    -fill '#5968c3' \
    -font Arial \
    -size 140x80 \
    -pointsize 190 \
    -gravity center \
    -draw "text 0,0 ALPHA" \
    -matte \
    -pointsize 16 \
    -gravity southeast \
    -draw "text 10,10 \"©2018 Hunter Ltd\"" \
    input.png \
    output.png
```

Which gives me a nice solid colour.

How do I make that colour 75% (say) transparent?

This what I currently have:

[image]

Comment: Try changing -fill '#5968c3'  to -fill '#BF5968c3'

Comment: @Bonzo That did not do what I thought it would… I now have the letters drawn in pink in a light pink rectangles.

Comment: I nice shade of pink? I wonder if the hex colour is cut off at 6 chracters? I wonder if a RGBA value would work: rgba(89,104,195,0.75)

Comment: Sadly not. \20char

Answer (score 1):

I do not use GraphicsMagick, but in Imagemagick, the following works fine by modifying the hex color to include alpha values (77).

Fully opaque ALPHA:

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:pink \
-fill "#5968c3" \
-font Arial \
-pointsize 150 \
-gravity center \
-draw "text 0,0 ALPHA" \
result1.png
```

[image]

Approx half transparent ALPHA:

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:pink \
-fill "#5968c377" \
-font Arial \
-pointsize 150 \
-gravity center \
-draw "text 0,0 ALPHA" \
result2.png
```

[image]

I do not think your -background transparent and -size 140x80 are doing anything in your command since you provide an input image. Typically, I use double quotes rather than single quotes. I do not know if this will help.